# Get redirected URL from initial link

Tags: c#, webrequest

I have this link
http://www.freshwap.me/engine/go.php?url=aHR0cDovL3JhcGlkZ2F0b3IubmV0L2ZpbGUvMmVhZDhlMGE1YTQ5YWZlODc4OTEwNmE5OGUyOTQ5MWEvQXNoYW1wb28uQW50aS5WaXJ1cy4xLjAuMy5GaW5hbC5NdWx0aWxhbmd1YWdlLnJhci5odG1s

I want to get redirected url from it, when I click it in freshwap.me it will go to
http://rapidgator.net/file/2ead8e0a5a49afe8789106a98e29491a/Ashampoo.Anti.Virus.1.0.3.Final.Multilanguage.rar.html

but when I copy and paste it on to address bar, it will redirect to freshwap homepage.

So, how can I get first link above by using webrequest.

my Code

```
WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
string finalUrl = myWebRespond.ResponseUri.ToString();
myWebRespond.Close();
```

Comment: Please use Fiddler and investigate what is happening when you navigate. Asking people to click on random Urls is not nice...

Comment: User is soliciting workers in answer comments.  ... and now here.

Comment: Penking Nguyen - asking for code is not welcome on SO. You forgot to specify rate you are willing to pay. Even if SO is not good place to search for contractors some people may be willing to do so if you offer attractive (i.e. $250+/hour @ 2weeks min) rate...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Fiddler to review the differences between the request made in the browser and from your application.

Most probably, you have not specified the [Referer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx) property on the `HttpWebRequest` instance. Another possible cause is that the page uses cookie.

Using Fiddler for this purpose is a generic approach for every case where you find trouble building web request code to download stuff.

In your specific case you should just take the `url` parameter from the initial address and use Base64 decoder to retrieve the actual URL (try it at [online decoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/)).

Comment: can you code for me ?